# Set Unkown Number of headers in ION request Android

Tags: android, android-ion

I am using [this](https://github.com/koush/ion) library for service requests and I was wondering if I could add unknown number of key-value headers in a loop like from a hashmap using this library and I could not find any way to do that.

Can set bodyParemeters through Map collection but not for headers. Anyone knows if it is possible let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

I am amazed by seeing that no one responded to this simple problem I figured out on my own.

```
 ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> headers;
```

and then we can loop Builder.Any.B

```
    Builders.Any.B b = Ion.with(mContext)
            .load(request_url);
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        BasicNameValuePair pair = headers.get(i);
        b.addHeader(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
    }
```